# Celery result shows disabled

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm new to celery. After I install celery in my django app, I run the following command in the Django shell:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.apps import apps

app = Celery('')
app.config_from_object('ns.settings')
@app.task                            
def add(x, y):   
   return x + y
```

I can get the result:

```
In [5]: add.delay(4,4)
Out[5]: <AsyncResult: f632d828-07d5-4f6b-b538-2aee6617b7ab>
```

I think the async task is built successfully but I can't get any result like this:

```
In [4]: result = add.delay(4,4)
Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {'information': 'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', 'product': 'RabbitMQ', 'copyright': 'Copyright (C) 2007-2018 Pivotal Software, Inc.', 'capabilities': {'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, 'connection.blocked': True, 'authentication_failure_close': True, 'direct_reply_to': True, 'basic.nack': True, 'per_consumer_qos': True, 'consumer_priorities': True, 'consumer_cancel_notify': True, 'publisher_confirms': True}, 'cluster_name': 'rabbit@rabbit', 'platform': 'Erlang/OTP 19.2.1', 'version': '3.6.15'}, mechanisms: ['AMQPLAIN', 'PLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
[13:49:41] amqp _on_start():340 Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {'information': 'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', 'product': 'RabbitMQ', 'copyright': 'Copyright (C) 2007-2018 Pivotal Software, Inc.', 'capabilities': {'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, 'connection.blocked': True, 'authentication_failure_close': True, 'direct_reply_to': True, 'basic.nack': True, 'per_consumer_qos': True, 'consumer_priorities': True, 'consumer_cancel_notify': True, 'publisher_confirms': True}, 'cluster_name': 'rabbit@rabbit', 'platform': 'Erlang/OTP 19.2.1', 'version': '3.6.15'}, mechanisms: ['AMQPLAIN', 'PLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
using channel_id: 1
[13:49:41] amqp __init__():108  using channel_id: 1
Channel open
[13:49:41] amqp _on_open_ok():445   Channel open

In [7]: result.ready()
Out[7]: False

In [8]: result.status
Out[8]: u'PENDING'
```

When the celery first start I see the following message:

```
tasks_1      |  -------------- celery@31a95a569866 v4.1.0 (latentcall)
tasks_1      | ---- **** ----- 
tasks_1      | --- * ***  * -- Linux-4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs-x86_64-with-debian-8.10 2018-06-01 13:14:32
tasks_1      | -- * - **** --- 
tasks_1      | - ** ---------- [config]
tasks_1      | - ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x7efc50ed6810
tasks_1      | - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
tasks_1      | - ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
tasks_1      | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
tasks_1      | -- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
tasks_1      | --- ***** ----- 
tasks_1      |  -------------- [queues]
tasks_1      |                 .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
tasks_1      |                 
tasks_1      |
```

The result has been disabled. I think this is because my backend setting according to [this](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#conf-cache-result-backend)

```
result_backend = 'cache'
#result_backend = 'cache+memcached://memcached:11211/'
cache_backend = 'memory'
task_create_missing_queues = True
task_track_started = True
task_default_queue = 'celery'
task_always_eager = False
task_eager_propagates = True
task_ignore_result = True
task_store_errors_even_if_ignored = True
```

I tried this setting or only the commented line. I got the same disabled problem.

Do you know how to fix this? If you want to see more result with certain command. I'll show you.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Thanks for the detailed write-up.  While you're here, check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50649422/edit) to include more information.